# Google play error 963 on app's version update

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I've published multiple apps using flavors and each one have multiple apks using `splits`. At first few users complain that they getting error 963 when trying to download the app from google play store but now, after version update, the complains number increased significantly. lot of users complains that they get error 963 and cant download the update.

Is there anything I can do from my side to prevent it from happening?

The apks size are ~30MB each and I've added `android:installLocation="preferExternal"` to manifest.

Comment: We are also seeing this issue - our APK is 62 MB. Did you add preferExternal after the complaints? Because I just tested with one such problematic device and completely removing the android:installLocation solved the issue - we had preferExternal in the manifest before that.

Comment: @markostamcar thanks I'll try it

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anything I can do from my side to prevent it from happening?

No. Some people publish articles [how to solve the issue](http://www.fixerrs.com/2015/07/google-play-store-error-963.html), but this is all from user perspective and is rather working the issue around, not fixing it. You, as developer, cannot do much about how google infrastructure or services work.

Comment: seems not likely.. they can download and update any other apps except mine so its seems like there is something I can change in my app to solve it

Comment: and what does it prove?

Answer (score 1):

Removing the `android:installLocation` attribute from the manifest seems to solve the issue.

Comment: It does, however it of course prevents app to be installed on external storage or to be moved there :( Dmide, have you just recently started seeing this issue? I have reached out to Google and they said it's a known issue and that they are looking into it.

Comment: Yes, I faced this issue during yesterday's update of my app and luckily I don't really have to keep this flag. It definitely has something to do with Play Services' recent updates, however I've failed to find any valuable info. Glad to hear that Google confirmed the problem.